# Rails Unitialized Constant with Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rubygems, initialization, koala

I recently was testing Koala. I got my auth token from Facebook's Graph API Graph Explorer, and pasted it into

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(my_auth_token)
```

for the create action of my Api::V1::PostsController. I did bundle install and gem install, and neither fixed my problem. When I do a create action on a local REST client to my

```
Api::V1::PostsController
```

my error message is:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::PostsController::my_auth_token)
```

I find it very strange that it is ignoring koala and just grabbing the really long authentication token. When I installed Koala for the first time, it also did not make a configuration file (config/initializers/koala.rb), which I thought was weird. I don't know what it should be if it has one though. What is going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: have you defined `my_auth_token` variable?

Comment: I just copied the entire token and pasted it. my_auth_token is just a placeholder for my long token. I'm also using Rails 4.1.4, so does Koala maybe have a different procedure for installing on Rails 4 and higher?

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. It was very silly. I did not make the auth token into a string (wrapped it with ""). Also, you may get an error like

```
Faraday::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

but to fix that, I just did this in the terminal:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```